# undefined method `calendar_for' (gem watu_table_builder)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Has anyone tried to use this gem lately?

https://github.com/watu/table_builder

I'm adding it to Gemfile, adding this to my view:

```
= calendar_for(@tasks) do |t|
  = t.head('mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun')
  = t.day do |day, tasks|
    = day.day
    - tasks.each do |task|
      = h(task.name)
```

And it gives the error mentioned in a title:

```
undefined method `calendar_for' for #<#<Class:0x000000071b2ae0>:0x00000004257458>
```

Comment: First of all, did you run `bundle install`?

Comment: Second, that doesn't look like embedded ruby code. The first line should read `<%= calendar_for(@tasks) do |t|%>` with the corresponding `<% end %>` tag after everything. I don't know if you just edited it for readability or not.